# ReuseStrategy not working with lazy loaded child routes (Cannot reattach ActivatedRouteSnapshot created from a different route)

Tags: angular

I have an App with some pages with filters and I want to keep the filters and the results so when I come back to the page it shows those filters and results. So I'm using ReuseStrategy to keep the state of some components, but it's not working well with lazy loaded child routes. While I navigate along first level of routes it works as I expect, keeping the state of the components I want. But if I navigate to a second level route and then visit another route and come back to its parent route, it stops working throwing the following error: **Cannot reattach ActivatedRouteSnapshot created from a different route**.

This is my ReuseStrategy class:

```
import { RouteReuseStrategy, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, DetachedRouteHandle } from '@angular/router';
interface RouteStorageObject {
  snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot;
  handle: DetachedRouteHandle;
}
export class CustomReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {
  storedRoutes: { [key: string]: RouteStorageObject } = {};
  private acceptedRoutes: string[] = [
    'page1',
    'page2',
    'page3'
  ];
  shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return this.acceptedRoutes.indexOf(route.data['key']) > -1;
  }
  store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
    const storedRoute: RouteStorageObject = {
      snapshot: route,
      handle: handle
    };
    this.storedRoutes[route.data['key']] = storedRoute;
  }
  shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    if (route.routeConfig.path === 'login') {
      this.storedRoutes = {};
      return false;
    }
    return !!route.data && !!this.storedRoutes[route.data['key']];
  }
  retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle {
    if (!route.data || !this.storedRoutes[route.data['key']]) {
      return null;
    }
    return this.storedRoutes[route.data['key']].handle;
  }
  shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig;
  }
}
```

My app-routing.module.ts:

```
...
export const routes: Routes = [
  ...
  { path: 'page1',
    loadChildren: 'app/features/page1.module#Page1Module',
    data: { key: 'page1' }
  },
  {
    path: 'page2',
    loadChildren: 'app/features/page2.module#Page2Module',
    data: { key: 'page2' }
  },
  { path: 'page3',
    loadChildren: 'app/features/page3.module#Page3Module',
    data: { key: 'page3' }
  },
  { path: 'another-page',
    loadChildren: 'app/features/another-page.module#AnotherPageModule',
    data: { key: 'another-page' }
  },
  { path: 'home', redirectTo: 'page1', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'page1', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
...
```

And the page1-routing.module.ts (page1 has sub pages):

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: Page1Component },
  {
    path: 'page1-1',
    loadChildren: './page1-1/page1-1.module#Page11Module',
    data: { key: 'page1-1' }
  },
  {
    path: 'page1-2',
    loadChildren: './page1-2/page1-2.module#Page12Module',
    data: { key: 'page1-2' }
  },
];
...
```

I have the following pages:

- Page 1 *(keep state)*

  - Page 1-1
  - Page 1-2
- Page 2 *(keep state)*
- Page 3 *(keep state)*
- Another page

Example on correct navigation (doesn't throw any error): Page 1 => Page 1-1 => Page 1 => Page 2 => Page 1

Example on wrong navigation (throws Error Cannot reattach ActivatedRouteSnapshot created from a different route): Page 1 => Page 1-1 => Page 2 => Page 1

Answer (score 0):

The best answer you can get is here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13869.

In general you will have to debug router page lookups to find out why router rejects saved routes.